# POP Down Gmail Locally (OS X 10.8)

Tags: macos, email, gmail, email-client, mail-server

Can anyone provide advice on how one might POP down gmail accounts locally to my system? I have lots of accounts for specific tasks. QPopper? Some local mail server software that I can run?

I dont want to use Apple Mail or Outlook to accomplish this. I want the fetching of mail to be separate from the UI I choose to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you indicate that you are running OS X 10.8 why not buy Server from the App store?  You can turn your computer into a mail server.  Then have Gmail forward it to you automatically.  All you would need is a DynDNS account if you have a Dynamic IP address (most ISP's give you a dynamic one and charge for static ones).  Tell gmail to forward it to your "server" and have your mac act as the server.  Then any OS can retrieve your email from your server...

Comment: #Everett - I have the Server.app too. My thought here is what if I am on a laptop and it is not always running, or lid closed, etc?

Comment: If you're on the laptop, it will still work.  If the lid is closed (it's asleep) you can set wake on LAN (this means LAN activity wakes up the computer even with the lid closed).  If the laptops off... Well, I don't have an answer for that, except that I never turn my laptop off.  This may be a swing and a miss, just a thought...